# How do I get an object out of query params in Ember 2?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

In Ember 2, for a URL with a query string of `?q[a]=1&q[b]=2`, how do I get those params in the controller?

I'm able to get a single string (`q=foo`) and an array (`q[]=1&q[]=2`), but I'm unable to get an object like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the parameters in the `route` and sending them to the `controller` by:

```
setupController(controller, model, transition) {
  this._super(...arguments);

  // transition.params contains params in the url
  // this.get('router.url') contains all query params

  // your method in the controller to handle the params
  controller.setQueryParams( ...your params... );
}
```